# NetSuite Save Search - Purchase Orders Received Before 11AM Today

Tags: netsuite

I created a NetSuite Saved Search for Drop Ship Purchase Orders (DSPOs) that are Pending Fulfillment. What formula and/or criteria would I need to add in order to only show DSPOs we received before 11AM today? This would include previous days, not just today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the Date field used is {datecreated}, you could use a 'Formula (Text)' type criteria with the following formula:

```
CASE WHEN {datecreated} <= TRUNC(sysdate) + 11/24 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

and set the criteria to 'is 1'

Comment: Thank you. This works perfectly and I also learned a couple new things with Saved Search formulas.